# Model method called in controller returning "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Working on some legacy code and essentially copying/pasting some functionality, but getting an error that isn't making sense to me.

In my controller I have a CASE statement setup that checks the for the current page a user is on, and determines if a text field needs to be checked by calling the model method valid_in_state?(). In the CASE statement, the method is called just fine when using it for the symbol :name. If I try to mimic that same behavior for :address I get an error returned with:

```
undefined method `valid_in_state?' for true:TrueClass
```

This doesn't make sense to me since I know the method is defined and available within the model and works for :name.

Here's the code shortened to what's relevant.

Model:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base

  # validation for names
  validates_presence_of :namelast,
                        :namefirst,
                        :if => :name_state?
  validates_length_of   :namelast,
                        :maximum  => 50,
                        :allow_blank => true,
                        :message => RESPONSE_TEXT['validation']['name_length'],
                        :if => :name_state?
  validates_length_of   :namefirst,
                        :maximum  => 50,
                        :allow_blank => true,
                        :message => RESPONSE_TEXT['validation']['name_length'],
                        :if => :name_state?
  validates_length_of   :namemiddle,
                        :maximum  => 50,
                        :allow_blank => true,
                        :message => RESPONSE_TEXT['validation']['name_length'],
                        :if => :name_state?
  validates_length_of   :namesuffix,
                        :maximum  => 4,
                        :allow_blank => true,
                        :message => RESPONSE_TEXT['validation']['name_length'],
                        :if => :name_state?

                        
  validates_presence_of :home_street,
                        :if => :address_state?


  def valid_in_state?(state)
    @state = state
    valid?
  end

  def state?(state)
    self.send("#{state}_state?")
  end
 

  private
    def name_state?
      @state == :name
    end
    def address_state?
      @state == :address
    end
end
```

Controller:

```
def update

    summons = get_summons(@current_person)

    if(params[:response])
      @response = Response.find(summons.summonsid)
      @response.attributes = params[:response]


    case UI_TEXT['buttons']['next']
    when params[:intro]            then
      return if correct_position_state_from_post?(:questionnaire, :intro)
      set_position_state(:questionnaire, :name)
      redirect_to name_questionnaire_url
    when params[:name]             then
      return if correct_position_state_from_post?(:questionnaire, :name)
      if @response.valid_in_state?(:name)
        @response.save
        if session[:return_to_contact]
          set_position_state(:questionnaire, :contact)
          redirect_to session[:return_to_contact]
          session[:return_to_contact] = nil
        else
          set_position_state(:questionnaire, :address)
          redirect_to address_questionnaire_url
        end
      else
        render :action=> "name"
      end
    when params[:address]          then
      return if correct_position_state_from_post?(:questionnaire, :address)
      #address validate
      if @response.valid_in_state?(:address)
        @response.save
      end
    end
end
```

My ruby on rails knowledge is limited, but to me this should work. Or at least the method should be recognized since it literally works for the :name area of the CASE statement.

Comment: The error says that your `@response` variable set to true, when you call the `valid_in_state` method. It might be setting it on @response.save action. You need to debug your code before valid_in_state method and check your @response and figure out where it sets to true

Comment: OOOOOOO are you saying that instead of @response being an object of my response model, it's just acting as variable? So then the variable `true` won't have a method called `valid_in_state?`. Wow ok, so I need to figure out why for `:name` it is treated as an object of my response class, but when it hits the `:address` case it is set to `true`. That's very helpful thank you.

Comment: yeap. its either sets it true at `@response.save` or in `valid_in_state` method itself as i can see. You return `valid?` from that method. One of them sets @response to true for sure.

Comment: Yes I do have another method that uses `valid?`. Thanks!

Comment: @darkinSyde Thanks for the nudge in the right direct. I was able to get everything going from your helpful tip.

Comment: You're welcome!